# Most efficient way of storing lots of string messages in SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

My app receiving approximately 2000 string messages per second, each message is about 300 characters long.

I need to store all messages in a DB. I'm using *SQL Express 2008*, and .*NET*.

I'm thinking of holding all data in memory till it reaches a certain limit (10000 messages = 5 seconds , for example), and then write it down all at once.

This way the data will be written to the hard drive every 5 seconds, instead of every second.

Does my approach is good enough? What approach should I use in order to achieve the following results?

1. messages are not piling up in memory
2. Hard drive won't commit suicide :)

Note: there is no need to parse the strings, the only thing is to store them by the order they arrived.

Comment: This sounds like a lot of data. A quick calculation tells me you'll need to store about 50 GB of data per day at which rate I don't think it's feasible to store it in a database. Is this data to be stored indefinitely or it gets processed and gradually removed?

Comment: And let's not forget the Express limitation of (IIRC) 10GB per database. You will hit that limitation in about 5 hours.

Comment: @CyberDude: Thanks for the quick reply. I prefer to store as much as I can. But since it is a lot of data, once I reach to a storage limit, I will erase some old data in order to make room for new.

Comment: @SWeko: I wasn't aware of such limit (DB Newbie). Is there other free DB without such limit? Maybe I should use regular files and compress them?

Comment: If you don't do SQL based queries on your strings then it may be a better idea to just store them as files. As there are so many of them you also need to store them in a partitioned folder structure because a very large amount of files in the same folder can cause issues when trying to access them. Zipping a 300 char string won't make a big difference, maybe if you can group more such strings on individual lines in the same file (say one file for each hour?).

Comment: @CyberDude: Yes it is possible to group an hour of messages on the same file. Can you please elaborate about the _partitioned folder structure_? I would much appreciate a word on how often should I write to the disk as well.

Comment: By partitioned I mean you need to devise a folder structure having as many levels needed in order to limit the number of files in a folder. Each file would be placed in a folder based on a naming convention. eg: file 'abcfoobar.txt' -> '\a\b\c\abcfoobar.txt', 'xyzsomething.txt' -> '\x\y\z\xyzsomething.txt' for a 3-level structure.

Comment: @CyberDude: Thanks man! You should have wrote an answer!

Comment: @CyberDude: Great! Just sum up the comments to a nice answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick calculation indicates that you may experience up to 50 GB of data per day. If there is no SQL specific processing to be done on this data then it doesn't seem feasible to store it in a database.

The next solution would be files on the disk and since you deal with simple text (not binary) then perhaps a quick compression would also help. However since the files would be so small (300 bytes), compression would not yield any sensible results. The data would need to be grouped in larger files, for instance one piece of data per line and one such file per day. This file would be sufficiently large so that compression would give satisfactory results if the disk space would become an issue.

If the space is not an issue and/or frequent processing of this data or even simultaneous processing of data from different days is to be expected then one piece of data per file would be a better choice. This solution, in turn, will bring the issue of having a very large number of files inside a folder which will not only bump against file system limitations but also create performance issues when working with these files, and these issues will affect the entire machine performance.

Storing and accessing a large number of files in a better manner is to use a partitioned folder storage. That is each file would have to have a unique name and will then be placed in a specific folder hierarchy according to its name. This approach has several advantages:

- keeps the number of files per folder manageable (when this number increases, one only needs to go one folder hierarchy deeper to increase the "storage availability" exponentially)
- easy to find a file's location or where to store a file based on the naming convention

Sample partitioning:

- file names follow this format: `yyyymmddhhss-<counter>.txt` (e.g.: `201104252345-1.txt`, `201104252345-2.txt`, etc)
- folder structure follows the time parts: `\yyyy\mm\dd\` or `yyyy\mm\dd\hh\` etc (as many levels as the solution would need to keep the number of files manageable)
- results in: `201104252345-1.txt` being stored as `2011\04\25\201104252345-1.txt`, etc

Answer (score 3):

If you describe more thoroughly what you want to do with these massive amounts of data after you have stored them, it will be easier to make a clear suggestion on what to do with it.

At the face of it, it sounds like too much data for a relational database to handle. I would rather devise a solution based on plain text files if all you want is storage. If you want to be able to search the text files, you can slowly index them with a service or console application behind the scenes.

The index can be built with [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) and what you index can be kept to a minimum since I hope you don't need to be able to search for absolutely everything you store in these text files.

Answer (score 1):

I won't do that in your situation.
Assuming:

> (2000 * 300) / 1024(kb) / 1024(mb) =  about 0.54 MB per second.
>
> One day have: 60(sec) * 60(min) * 24(hour) = 86400 seconds.
>
> 0.54 * 86400 = 43200 MB per day.
>
> If you will use UTF-8 encoding the size will be twice bigger!
>   (varchar versus nvarchar)

It mean you will get about **40 GB** per day groth. Your express server wont survive even if you write insert query each 5 sec even 10 or 20 sec. Consider index rebuilding for good query performance, backuping the database in particular time period and other database stuff you have to carry about. Your database won't handle requests.

I would recommend you storing strings **in text files**(*if your text will be rarely read by end user otherwise I recommend using some index engine (Lucene maybe)*) and **cache** them in application server. Store only path of those files in database.

> Note. It's only my own solution based on some facts and expirience.

**EDIT**

Using application you will get more control with your data. You can send files via HTTP to other server you can compress files etc.